# Docker inside Windows guest virtual machine

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker

I use Debian Jessie as a VirtualBox host.
I have a Windows 7 virtual machine guest, what I use for development purposes.
I want to install docker.
In order to install docker for Windows I need Boot2docker.exe.
Boot2docker itself is a VirtualBox virual machine.
It requires enable VT-x.
That doesn't seem to work.
VirtualBox error message:

```
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)

E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Console
IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Comment: There's a chance that virtualization extensions aren't enabled on your physical host.  Reboot your machine, go into the BIOS, and check.  Then make sure VT-X is explicitly enabled on your VirtualBox VMs: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=17090

Comment: I have checked them, they are already well-confugired.

Comment: Drag.  This link might also be applicable: https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/issues/14

Comment: That doesn't sound like a smart idea at all. You have a Linux host with a Windows VM. Now you want to install a VM inside this VM to run a Linux in which you want to install a container host to run applications inside. Xzibit would like that.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig: This sounds perfectly plausible. Suppose I'm writing software in Linux, and I want to deploy it to Windows via a Docker container. If I want to test such a deployment and I only have Linux on my desktop, it seems natural to try to install Windows inside a VM, and then install Docker inside the Windows VM. (It might not be what OP is asking about, though.)

Answer (score 3):

You want to run Docker client on your Windows development VM. Now you want to create a boot2docker linux VM inside the windows VM to run the docker deamon on. I think it's better to run the docker deamon on your Debian host system and let the docker client talk to the host system.

See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#the-docker-client

Comment: How can you configure the docker client on windows to communicate with other any arbitrary daemon?

The only explanations I see in the official documentation always go through docker-machine created guests vms

Comment: I have been trying this, but can't figure out how to connect Docker on Windows to connect as a client to Docker on the host machine.
Does anyone know how this works?